# Hibernate : How to view the query output with single column in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hi I'm using the below code to view the column values of firstName from the table Employee but im hitting the below error:

**ERROR:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.servlet.prgm.Employee
    at com.servlet.prgm.ManageEmployee.listEmployees(ManageEmployee.java:90)
    at com.servlet.prgm.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:33)

**CODE :**

```
   Query sql = session.createQuery("select firstName FROM Employee");
     List employees = sql.list();
     for (Iterator iterator = employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
         {
         Employee employee = (Employee)iterator.next();
         employee.getFirstName();
         System.out.println("First Name" +employee.getFirstName());
         }
     tx.commit();
     }catch (HibernateException e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     e.printStackTrace(); 
  }finally {
     session.close(); 
  }
```

**Employee.class**

```
  package com.servlet.prgm;

  public class Employee {
   private int id;
   private String firstName; 
   private String lastName;   
   private int salary;  

   public Employee() {}
   public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
      this.firstName = fname;
      this.lastName = lname;
      this.salary = salary;
   }
   public Employee(String fname){
       this.firstName=fname;
   }
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

Apologies if my formatting is not correct , I'm a newbie I will improve soon.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting a single scalar value so Hibernate is actually returning a list of strings:

```
try {
    Query sql = session.createQuery("select firstName FROM Employee");
    List firstNames = sql.list();
    for (Iterator iterator = firstNames.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
    {
        string firstName = (string)iterator.next();
        System.out.println("First Name" + firstName);
    }
    tx.commit();
}catch (HibernateException e) {
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}finally {
   session.close(); 
}
```